# Is there some special requirement to use Cloud Build Private Workers Pools?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm working with Cloud Build at my company and I need to use workers with access on my VPC network.

I've followed the instructions from the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/worker-pools/create), but the command responds this message:

```
X@cloudshell:~ (PROJECT_ID)$ gcloud builds worker-pools create POOL_NAME \
--project=PROJECT_ID /
--region=southamerica-east1 /
--peered-network=projects/PROJECT_ID/global/networks/NETWORK_NAME /
--worker-machine-type=e2-standard-2

ERROR: (gcloud.builds.worker-pools.create) ALREADY_EXISTS: project PROJECT_ID already has 0 WorkerPools, and the max is 0
```

The pool creation does not work neither in Cloud Shell Terminal, nor the Console. Both exit with the same `project PROJECT_ID already has 0 WorkerPools, and the max is 0`.

The documentation (https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/create-manage-private-pools) says that:

> You can create 10 private pools per Cloud project per region.

So why all of my projects are with 0 max WorkerPools?
Am I missing something?

* My organization and billing are fine. 
** I have those IAM roles for this project:

> Cloud Build WorkerPool Owner 
> Owner 
> Organization Administrator 
> Kubernetes Engine Admin

Comment: I got the same issue today. I directly asked Google cloud product team. I let you know when I have updates

Comment: No news for now, but I tested again this morning (in france) and it works!

Comment: It seems that was a temporary error on GCP. It's working today, thank you.